# Why pytest does not catch exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, flask, pytest

I have a `pytest` test case like below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = SampleApp().setup()
    yield app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()

def test_get_nonexistent_user(client, app):
    with pytest.raises(NotFound) as err:
        user = client.get('/users/5d4001f799556f10b7462e20')

    assert err.type is NotFound
```

What I have read from [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises) I should be able to catch this exception. What I receive instead is as below:

```
1 failed in 0.25 seconds
```

And I see `NotFound` error in `traceback` error, so I'm sure code is raising the exception I expect it to.

Comment: Because the exception is caught by Django middleware, which prints the traceback and sends the 404 response. If you want to use `client`, assert `client.get().status_code == 404`. If you want to catch `NotFound`, test the view with request factory instead.

Comment: @hoefling It is actually `Flask` not `Django`. By doing what you've suggested I get `E AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: usercollection`

Comment: I'm not that much familiar with `flask`, but it will also implement the error handling according to WSGI spec - if an error is raised while processing an endpoint, it is caught and transformed in a response with an appropriate status code, e.g. 404 on a `NotFound` raised, or 403 on `PermissionDenied`, or 500 on an arbitrary one. `pytest` behaves correctly here as no exception is raised in `client.get`.